# Submitting form after validations using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, form

This is my simple jQuery form validation/submit logic and it is working perfectly fine. But still I am posting this to see if someone check the logic and suggest me if there is any other simple way to get the same results.

In my form I put all input boxes and select into `.valid1` class, all checkbox and radio buttons to `.valid2` class. I am just wondering is there any way we can do this by putting all input sources under a single class.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#sbutton").click(function(){
           var submitflag = false;
           var validflag = true; 
           validform();
//           alert(submitflag);
           if (submitflag){
              $("form").submit();
           }
           function validform(){
              $(".valid1").each(function(){
                 if ($(this).find("input").val() === ''){
//                    alert("I am input"); 
                    $(this).find(".error1").html($(this).find("label").html() +" " + "is required");
                    validflag = false;
                 }else{
                    $(this).find(".error1").html(""); 
                 }
                 if ($(this).find("select").val() === ''){
//                    alert("I am select"); 
                    $(this).find(".error2").html($(this).find("label").html() +" " + "is required");
                    validflag = false;
                 }else{
                    $(this).find(".error2").html(""); 
                 }

              });
              $(".valid2").each(function(){
                 if (!$(this).find("input:checked").val()){
//                    alert("I am cbox"); 
                    $(this).find(".error3").html($(this).find("label").html() +" " + "is required");
                    $(this).find(".error4").html("Agree terms and conditions");
                    validflag = false;
                 }else{
                    $(this).find(".error3, .error4").html(""); 
                 } 
              });
              if(validflag){submitflag = true;}
           }
         });
});
```

Comment: It would be better if you attached your HTML code. Anyway, it seems to me that you can organize the error `div`s in one style, so that each error `div` has the one class.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `submitflag`. The `validform` function could simply return the value of `validflag`, which should be declared inside that function, not in the outer scope.

> In my form I put all input boxes and select into .valid1 class, all checkbox and radio buttons to .valid2 class. I am just wondering is there any way we can do this by putting all input sources under a single class.

Sure. You just need to adjust some of the dom selectors a little bit, so that they are specific enough to match the right kind of input, for example by adding a condition on the `type` attribute, to make sure that text input and checkboxes are correctly distinguished.